# How can I delete items from list, that are null?

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get all links from webpage, click them and check if they are working, but i want to remove the one's with URL containing null and logoff from my list because of the nullpointerexception and driver logging off from webpage. How can you suggest me to do that? Keep in mind that I am new to java.

Here is my code that I've got so far:

```
private static String[] links = null;
private static int linksCount = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

     driver.get("webpage that I'm trying to test");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.findElement(By.id("UserNameOrEmail")).sendKeys("username");
     driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("password");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/form/div[3]/input")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content-main']/div/div/a[3]/h3")).click();


     List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
     linksCount = alllinks.size();
     System.out.println("Number of links: "+linksCount);
     links= new String[linksCount];  
     //remove items from list (null, logoff... )

     // print all the links  
     System.out.println("List of links Available: ");  
     for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
     {
     links[i] = alllinks.get(i).getAttribute("href");
     System.out.println(alllinks.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
     } 
     // click on each link
     for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
     {
     driver.navigate().to(links[i]);
     System.out.println("Link  "+links[i]);  
     }

}
```

Comment: `someList.stream().removeIf(e -> e == null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can avoid having links without `href` attribute in the first place*.

Replace:

```
List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

with:

```
List<WebElement> alllinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href]"));
```

To filter out the "log off" link:

```
a[href]:not([href$=LogOff])
```

Comment: thanks, it's a really good idea, but how do I deal with a link that logs off from the page? Do I need to remove that from my list so it will not be clicked or there is a better solution?

Comment: @ŽygimantasDirma we might as well filter it out with a CSS selector. Can you provide the logout link HTML representation?